# Large Gen0 GC size after hours of Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I am running .NET 4.8 x64 (4.8.4300.0) where after a ca. 14h stress test the GC times are much higher than at the start. With PerfView I can see that the size of Gen0 Heap has grown a lot. Are there known issues with Gen0 Heap size and .NET 4.8?

**Iteration 10**
[image]
[image]

- Total CPU Time: 136,245 msec
- Total GC CPU Time: 7,171 msec
- Total Allocs : 10,023.772 MB
- GC CPU MSec/MB Alloc : 0.715 MSec/MB
- Total GC Pause: 8,361.5 msec
- % Time paused for Garbage Collection: 5.5%
- % CPU Time spent Garbage Collecting: 5.3%
- Max GC Heap Size: 460.052 MB
- Peak Process Working Set: 1,166.688 MB
- Peak Virtual Memory Usage: 7,314.285 MB

**Iteration 300**
[image]
[image]

- Total CPU Time: 141,466 msec
- Total GC CPU Time: 14,364 msec
- Total Allocs : 10,235.755 MB
- GC CPU MSec/MB Alloc : 1.403 MSec/MB
- Total GC Pause: 22,767.4 msec
- % Time paused for Garbage Collection: 13.6%
- % CPU Time spent Garbage Collecting: 10.2%
- Max GC Heap Size: 887.517 MB
- Peak Process Working Set: 1,916.793 MB
- Peak Virtual Memory Usage: 8,047.583 MB

When I plot from ETW the CPU consumption of GC, Background GC and Induced GC for various iteration counts I find a clear correlation with increased GC costs and iteration count.
[image]

The strange thing is that the managed heap has not really become much larger. This does not look like a managed memory leak (ok it leaks a bit but not that much) but some GC issue or did I look at the data in the wrong way?

**Update 1**
Here is the call stack of the GC which seems to be pretty expensive:

```
Stack Tag, Stack, Weight (in view) (ms)
4, ,   Background GC, , 245.131400
5, , , [Root], 245.131400
6, , ,   ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart, 245.131400
7, , ,   kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk, 245.131400
8, , ,   clr.dll!Thread::intermediateThreadProc, 245.131400
9, , ,   clr.dll!<lambda_29e7ea55b6ca6bda8a02df3a0a3e58b1>::operator(), 245.131400
10, , ,   clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::bgc_thread_function, 245.131400
11, , ,   clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::gc1, 245.131400
12, , ,   clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::background_mark_phase, 245.131400
13, , ,   |- clr.dll!GCScan::GcScanHandles, 203.131000
14, , ,   |    clr.dll!Ref_TraceNormalRoots, 203.131000
15, , ,   |    clr.dll!HndScanHandlesForGC, 203.131000
16, , ,   |    clr.dll!TableScanHandles, 203.131000
17, , ,   |    clr.dll!BlockScanBlocksWithoutUserData, 203.131000
18, , ,   |    clr.dll!ScanConsecutiveHandlesWithoutUserData, 203.131000
19, , ,   |    |- clr.dll!PromoteRefCounted, 202.131100
20, , ,   |    |    |- clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::background_promote, 196.131800
21, , ,   |    |    |    clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::background_mark_simple, 196.131800
22, , ,   |    |    |    clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::background_mark_simple1, 196.131800
23, , ,   |    |    |    |- clr.dll!WKS::gc_heap::background_mark_simple1<itself>, 186.138400
```

Not sure which objects can make that so expensive. But it looks CPU dominated. This is one Gen2 GC which did take over 250ms to complete

The Induced Gen2 GCs seem to originate from Background GC
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to look at a dump,  and see what are the gc roots, abd what objest are allocated?

Comment: Yes I have dumps but there are no large differences which would explain 14s of increased GC time. It is a little tricky to get the dumps at the right time of the test but so far I have not found for e.g. 300 iterations a multiple of 300 added objects.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills: I would love to but this is a large application. I think I will first look at memory leaks and pinned memory. I suspect that the memory compression process has also some part in this perf drop...

Comment: Indeed interesting data. Similar amount of allocations per gen and only ~2 times bigger heap it introduces over 7x longer gen2 GC pauses. What's interesting - all your gen2 GCs are "induced". Why? For me now it looks like forcing non-productive GCs. Could you look at "Condemned reasons for GCs" in GCStats at *Induced* column? And recording session with `Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime:GCKeyword:Informational:@StacksEnabled=true` will allow you to record explicit GC call stack traces.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: I know why GCs are induced. Part of it are due the the HandleCollector in Windows Forms but the majority is due to when we close a large file in the application we force with an induced GC the flush the large object model to be fast when the next file is loaded and to release memory. The induced GCs are therfore expected and I know where they are coming from.

Comment: Ok, I see your update. Your stacktrace is from concurrent marking GC phase, which while CPU-intensive, probably does not explain pauses. Now, we would need to understand long `2NI` GCs (are they compacting?) and/or why all those `2Bi` GCs take ~200ms. For background GC there are two "pauses": 1) initial roots mark and 2) final root mark (see [slides 9-10 from my series](https://goodies.dotnetos.org/files/03.%20NET%20GC%20Internals%20-%20Concurrent%20Mark%20phase.pdf)). Maybe you will be able to correlate pauses with number of objects in `BGCDrainMark`/`BGCRevisit` events?

Comment: @KonradKokosa: I think the PromoteRefCounted method is the one which becomes more expensive over time. This looks like a strong handle leak which could relate to UI Automation COM objects. Although not big they might be more expensive to collect than others. The BGC events are with my default profile filtered out to keep the resulting ETL small. I guess I will need to track WeakReferences and others from memory dumps.

Comment: This post looks also interesting: https://yizhang82.dev/ref-counted-handle

Answer (score 1):

After taking dumps I have found many RefCounted objects namely **MS.Internal.Automation.ValueProviderWrapper** which keep a lot UI objects alive via UI Automation. I think refcounting works which means that the other process which drives the UI is leaking UI Automation objects. At least the increased GC costs can be explained now.

MemAnalyzer has helped also a lot: https://github.com/Alois-xx/MemAnalyzer

to be sure to look at the right things. PerfView is pretty bad at counting objects due to its stack sampling approach. With Memanalyzer and you can gather exact numbers and diffs.

With

```
C:\dumps>for %i in (*.dmp) do memanalyzer -f MemoryDump_5.dmp -f2 %i -o Diff_5_%i.csv
```

[image]

If I then add a column of the form = ObjectDiff/IterationDiff I can calculate the leakage rate per iteration for different dumps. If we leak one object per iteration I just need to search for objects around 1 or a multiple of it to find leaks which are related per iteration which makes it much easier to reason about root causes.

[image]